# Laravel manual auth - Never works

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to make Auth for an API Rest manually, but the response for Auth::attempt is always false.

Route

```
Route::group(["prefix"=>"api"], function(){
    Route::post('/login', [
        'as'    =>  'checkLogin',
        'uses'  =>  'LoginCtrl@checkLogin'
    ]);
});
```

Controller

```
class LoginCtrl extends Controller
{
    public function checkLogin(Request $request){
        $input = $request->all();
        if(Auth::attempt(['username' => $input['user'], 'password' => $input['password']])){
            $data = ["response"=>true,"access_token"=>"test"];
        }else{
            $data = ["response"=>false,"access_token"=>"none"];
        }
        return response()->json($data);
    }
}
```

I have userd `Hash::make` to encrypt the password on the user creation.

My model is:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = "usuarios";
    protected $username = 'username';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'username', 'password'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        //'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function access_token(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\AccessToken');
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

```
$user = new User();
$user->username = "myFreshUsername";
$user->password = Hash::make('userPwd');
$user->save();
```

Thats my user creation. If this helps I didn't launch `php artisan make:auth', may this order be necessary?

Comment: Did you change anything in `\config\auth.php`? Can you login without using `$request->input()` values (ie `\Auth::attempt(["username" => "someone", "password" => "password"]);`)

Comment: also share your user creation method, so we can look into password encryption. May be encryption process which is you doing is wrong.

Comment: Ok, I will post my user creation @Qazi. Tim I did not change anything in `\config\auth.php` its a fresh laravel 5.2 installation.

Comment: @ProgramadorAdagal whats your method type? $_POST?

Comment: As you can see in `Route::post` the answer is yes, my method is post.

Comment: @ProgramadorAdagal are you passing a json data and using postman?

Comment: No, I am using an external angular Application (dev by me) thats throws me no error and gets the response without any fail. Anyway the method its not important cause I receive the response correctly.

Comment: @ProgramadorAdagal you get the values correctly?

Comment: Thats what I said, this is the response got in angular: `{"response":false,"access_token":"none"}`

Answer (score 1):

of course it always false because you did not use correct way to get the json in your request using laravel
the correct way is

```
$input  = $request->json()->all();
```

not

```
$input = $request->all();
```

so your controller would be like this

```
class LoginCtrl extends Controller
{
    public function checkLogin(Request $request){
        $input  = $request->json()->all();
        if(Auth::attempt(['username' => $input['user'], 'password' => $input['password']])){
            $data = ["response"=>true,"access_token"=>"test"];
        }else{
            $data = ["response"=>false,"access_token"=>"none"];
        }
        return response()->json($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know the json() methos of the Request object. On the other hand, still gets false on `Auth::attempt`

Comment: @ProgramadorAdagal did you try to var_dump($request->json()->all()); and see the result ?

Comment: `array(2) {
  ["user"]=>
  string(3) "dev"
  ["password"]=>
  string(11) "xxxxxx"
}`

Comment: is that the result of $request->json()->all() or $request->all() ?

Comment: $request->json()->all()

Comment: how about try creating new user and trying it again. also can I see your updated php script

Comment: Same result. `array(2) {
  ["user"]=>
  string(3) "dgl"
  ["password"]=>
  string(3) "xxx"
}` Auth attempt result: `{"response":false,"access_token":"none"}`

Comment: Can I see your php code in register and login. Screen shot

Comment: Is posted on my question

Comment: I mean how about your registration did your registration get your correct data?

Comment: What?? I did not understand.

Comment: I want to know if your registration code successfully save the correct user data. like the username and password

Comment: Yes, It is saved in database. I don't know if Hash::make or bcrypt functions are translating alright (I have this `$2y$10$t8RXYy/afaEuIpE8GIk2bOvbHsQoj0fhGPxmo/3UqJABKVA4I4pHC` in password field)

Comment: @ProgramadorAdagal strange that should be working by now. since you get the right data. Can I see your updated login script

Comment: I know, thats the point, I have no idea why it is no working. I have a table manually created for users with email, password and username (no more fields), could be possible fail not having exact laravel auth tables? I dont have a migrations, password_resets, and all the fields on users table that laravels uses (thats because I dont really need any of them)

Comment: how about updating your password in your table manually to the Hash::make('password'); value to check it really working

Comment: Of course I Had tried that before asking. And tried with a lot of different users

Comment: can you send the screen shot of your update login script